# Can anybody explain the time complexity for the below code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
void function(int n)
{
    int p = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
        for (int j=n/2; j<=n; j = j++)
            for (int k=1; k<=n; k = k * 2)
                p++;
}
```

Explaination for the time complexity would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop executes  + 1 times.

Per iteration of the outer loop, the middle loop iterates ⁄2 + 1 times. The number of iterations is independent on the value of .

Per iteration of the middle loop, the inner loop iterates log₂() + 1 times because the value of  doubles in each iteration. The number of iterations is independent on the value of  or .

So you need to multiply these iteration counts to know how many times `p++` is executed, i.e.:

( + 1)(⁄2 + 1)(log₂() + 1)

The highest order term of this expression is ½ ²log₂(), which is:

O(²log).